# Прочитать файл в pandas из txt

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, csv, txt

Выгрузка возможна только в таком виде в файле txt:

```
|conversation_id        |user_id    |interval_start     |interval_end       |
|-----------------------|-----------|-------------------|-------------------|
|477314657_1000980316   |1000980316 |2021-04-05 07:17:39|[NULL]             |
|591462555_1378949942   |591462555  |2021-04-05 07:01:29|[NULL]             |
|127736043_591462555    |591462555  |2021-04-05 07:01:23|[NULL]             |
```

Пытался считать `pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='|')` не получилось.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перегнать эту таблицу в pandas?

Comment: Скиньте скрин, как у вас записан файл txt

Comment: Не надо скринов. Часть файла в студию.

Comment: Ну можно и так.

Comment: Не могу скрин прикрепить, вот пример файла: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-carson-wovlo?file=/example.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("001.txt", sep="|", usecols=[1,2,3,4], skiprows=[1])
```

df:

```
    conversation_id         user_id         interval_start          interval_end
0   477314657_1000980316    1000980316      2021-04-05 07:17:39     [NULL]
1   591462555_1378949942    591462555       2021-04-05 07:01:29     [NULL]
2   127736043_591462555     591462555       2021-04-05 07:01:23     [NULL]
```

чтобы не считать количество столбцов вручную:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("001.txt", sep="|", skiprows=[1])
df = df.iloc[:,1:-1]
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Есть ли вариант, без ручного ввода количества столбцов? А  то файлов много и нужно в кажддом считать.

Comment: Разобрался) Сделал так 

`from collections import Counter
with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    content = f.readline()
count_cols = Counter(content)['|']
usecols=list(range(1, count_cols))`

Comment: Спасибо, за дополнение!

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы автоматически удалять пустые столбцы можно сделать так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s*\|\s*", skiprows=[1]).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
```

результат:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
        conversation_id     user_id       interval_start interval_end
0  477314657_1000980316  1000980316  2021-04-05 07:17:39       [NULL]
1  591462555_1378949942   591462555  2021-04-05 07:01:29       [NULL]
2   127736043_591462555   591462555  2021-04-05 07:01:23       [NULL]

In [32]: df.columns.to_list()
Out[32]: ['conversation_id', 'user_id', 'interval_start', 'interval_end']

In [33]: df.dtypes
Out[33]:
conversation_id    object
user_id             int64
interval_start     object
interval_end       object
dtype: object
```